# Golang. What to use? http.ServeFile(..) or http.FileServer(..)?

Tags: go, server

I'm a little bit confused. Much of examples shows usage of both: `http.ServeFile(..)` and `http.FileServer(..)`, but seems they have very close functionality. Also I have found no information about how to set custom NotFound handler.

```
// This works and strip "/static/" fragment from path
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))
http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))

// This works too, but "/static2/" fragment remains and need to be striped manually
http.HandleFunc("/static2/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, r.URL.Path[1:])
})

http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
```

I've tried to read source code and both of them use `serveFile(ResponseWriter, *Request, FileSystem, string, bool)` underlying function. However `http.FileServer` return `fileHandler` with its own `ServeHTTP()` method and make some preparation work before serving file (eg path.Clean()).

So why need this separation? Which method better to use? And how can I set custom NotFound handler, for example when requested file not found?

Comment: The biggest diffence is that `http.FileServer` is `http.Handler` while `http.ServeFile` is not.

Comment: Thanks, I know it, but it doesn't make plight better to me)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The main difference is that `http.FileServer` does effectively almost 1:1 mapping of an HTTP prefix with a filesystem. In plain english, it serves up an entire directory path. and all its children.

Say you had a  directory called `/home/bob/static` and you had this setup:

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("/home/bob/static"))
http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static", fs))
```

Your server would take requests for e.g. `/static/foo/bar` and serve whatever is at `/home/bob/static/foo/bar` (or 404)

In contrast, the `ServeFile` is a lower level helper that can be used to implement something similar to FileServer, or implement your own path munging potentially, and any number of things. It simply takes the named local file and sends it over the HTTP connection. By itself, it won't serve a whole directory prefix (unless you wrote a handler that did some lookup similar to FileServer)

**NOTE** Serving up a filesystem naively is a potentially dangerous thing (there are potentially ways to break out of the rooted tree) hence I recommend that unless you *really* know what you're doing, use `http.FileServer` and `http.Dir` as they include checks to make sure people can't break out of the FS, which `ServeFile` doesn't.

*Addendum*
Your secondary question, how do you do a custom NotFound handler, unfortunately, is not easily answered. Because this is called from internal function `serveFile` as you noticed, there's no super easy place to break into that. There are potentially some sneaky things like intercepting the response with your own `ResponseWriter` which intercepts the 404 response code, but I'll leave that exercise to you.

Comment: Very, very good! It is exactly what I want to hear! Big thank you!) My English is not mother tongue, so could you tell me what does "munging" mean?)

Comment: Munging: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_wrangling ..  so he basically means creating your own path mapping

Comment: Or even https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mung_(computer_term)

"It is sometimes used for vague data transformation steps that are not yet clear to the speaker.[2] Common munging operations include removing punctuation or html tags, data parsing, filtering, and transformation."

Comment: Note, to serve a directory on disk (/tmp) under an alternate URL path (/tmpfiles/), make sure you include the trailing slash. E.g. the example above to serve files in `/tmp` with the route `static` would become: `http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))`

Comment: Good advice on the safety concerns – `http.FileServer` is probably the safest approach for most use cases.

Answer (score 7):

Here a handler which sends a redirect to "/" if file is not found. This comes in handy when adding a fallback for an Angular application, as suggested [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment), which is served from within a golang service.

**Note:** This code is not production ready. Only illustrative (at best :-)

```
    package main

    import "net/http"

    type (
        // FallbackResponseWriter wraps an http.Requesthandler and surpresses
        // a 404 status code. In such case a given local file will be served.
        FallbackResponseWriter struct {
            WrappedResponseWriter http.ResponseWriter
            FileNotFound          bool
        }
    )

    // Header returns the header of the wrapped response writer
    func (frw *FallbackResponseWriter) Header() http.Header {
        return frw.WrappedResponseWriter.Header()
    }

    // Write sends bytes to wrapped response writer, in case of FileNotFound
    // It surpresses further writes (concealing the fact though)
    func (frw *FallbackResponseWriter) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
        if frw.FileNotFound {
            return len(b), nil
        }
        return frw.WrappedResponseWriter.Write(b)
    }

    // WriteHeader sends statusCode to wrapped response writer
    func (frw *FallbackResponseWriter) WriteHeader(statusCode int) {
        Log.Printf("INFO: WriteHeader called with code %d\n", statusCode)
        if statusCode == http.StatusNotFound {
            Log.Printf("INFO: Setting FileNotFound flag\n")
            frw.FileNotFound = true
            return
        }
        frw.WrappedResponseWriter.WriteHeader(statusCode)
    }

    // AddFallbackHandler wraps the handler func in another handler func covering authentication
    func AddFallbackHandler(handler http.HandlerFunc, filename string) http.HandlerFunc {
        Log.Printf("INFO: Creating fallback handler")
        return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            Log.Printf("INFO: Wrapping response writer in fallback response writer")
            frw := FallbackResponseWriter{
                WrappedResponseWriter: w,
                FileNotFound:          false,
            }
            handler(&frw, r)
            if frw.FileNotFound {
                Log.Printf("INFO: Serving fallback")
                http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusSeeOther)
            }
        }
    }
```

It can be added as in this example (using goji as mux):

```
    mux.Handle(pat.Get("/*"),
        AddFallbackHandler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("./html")).ServeHTTP, "/"))
```