# Go http: difference between serving /static and /static/

Tags: http, go, handler

I have a terrible confusion concerning `http.FileServer` and slashes.

I need to serve a script to a html page. In the directory I'm working I have the page `index.html` and I have a `static` directory with `myscript.js` inside of it.

First question: is it correct to write

```
<script src="/static/myscript.js"></script>
```

? I have also seen `src="static/myscript.js"` and I don't know if there is a reason for using one or the other (but I guess it influences the handler we have to write on the server).

Let's suppose we settle for the first version. Second question: on the server side, I want to register the handler for directory `static`. Inspired by [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793619/golang-what-to-use-http-servefile-or-http-fileserver), I do:

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))
http.Handle("/static", http.StripPrefix("/static", fs))
```

but I get a `404`. However, if I use:

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))
http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))
```

with the ending slashes, it works fine!

I'm really new to web servers, so I would appreciate any explanation that includes what are the actual addresses passed around by functions. For example, I don't know (and I can't figure it out from the `net/http` documentation ) what is the  address that is passed to the handler when serving a `/static` request. I guess it's `/static/myscript.js` since we are using `http.StripPrefix` but I have no actual way of proving it.

Comment: Related: [Why do I need to use http.StripPrefix to access my static files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945310/why-do-i-need-to-use-http-stripprefix-to-access-my-static-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http.Handle("/static", http.StripPrefix("/static", fs))` registers a **fixed name** pattern.

`http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))` registers a **rooted subtree** pattern.

The former matches only requests where `URL.path = "/static"`. The latter matches every path that starts with `"/static/"`. The `404` indicates that it could not match any pattern for the given request, not that the requested file wasn't found. (It does not even get to execute the `FileServer`'s handler!)

---

And to answer your first question:

```
<script src="/static/myscript.js"></script>
```

URLs starting with a slash `/` are **absolute**. That means it does not matter on what page you are, it will always append to the domain name e.g. `example.com/some/page` + `/static/myscript.js` = `example.com/static/myscript.js`

```
<script src="static/myscript.js"></script>
```

Is a **relative** path. That means it will be appended to URL of the currently visited page e.g. `example.com/some/page` + `static/myscript.js` = `example.com/some/page/static/myscript.js`