# Golang How remove the last trailing slash on static serving

Tags: go

I want to remove the last trailing slash in the path, ex: **localhost:8080/Login/** --> **localhost:8080/Login**. In code, I use **/login** instead of **/login/** but **css** and **js** don't work, please help!

This is my code:

Go file:

```
func main() {
    fileServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir("pages"))
    //http.Handle("/Login/", http.StripPrefix("/Login/", fileServer))
    http.Handle("/Login", http.StripPrefix("/Login", fileServer))

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

HTTP file:

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap/bootstrap-4.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-4.3.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: do you have 'js' and 'css' folders inside your 'pages' folder?

Comment: I store 'js' and 'css' folders inside the 'pages' folder, if I use '/login/', it works, but not for '/login'

Comment: update your code. `http.Handle("/Login/", http.StripPrefix("/Login", fileServer))`. reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793619/golang-what-to-use-http-servefile-or-http-fileserver

Comment: It works, but on the web browser, when I type **localhost:8080/Login** and press Enter, the path will automatically change to **localhost:8080/Login/**, I want to remove the last slash, the url must be **localhost:8080/Login**

Comment: This is how the default muxer works and cannot be changed without using a different muxer.

Comment: I think you don't really understand what's going on. It's hard to see how the url changing has anything to do with js and css files not loading.

Comment: @Volker, registering the same handler for /x/ and /x disables the redirect. https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux

Comment: @Peter Neat trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

user10753492 is correct. Because you're using rooted paths for the CSS and JS files the trailing slash doesn't matter as far as the requests for the CSS and JS files are concerned.

As for the redirect to /Login/: [this behavior is documented along with instructions on how to prevent that](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux):

> If a subtree has been registered and a request is received naming the subtree root without its trailing slash, ServeMux redirects that request to the subtree root (adding the trailing slash). This behavior can be overridden with a separate registration for the path without the trailing slash.

So if you don't want the redirect, register the same handler for both /Login and /Login/.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically mounting your frontend at "/Login".

But your js and css are being requested from "/"

So of course they won't be loaded.

You have to either:

1. Change your css and js references to be "/Login/js/...." and "/Login/css/..."

   This doesn't seem like what you actually want to do though
2. Or, mount the frontend at "/"

   ```
   http.Handle("/", fileServer)
   ```

Answer (score -3):

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
)
func main() {
  var s string = "localhost:8080/Login/"
  fmt.Println(s)
  for _,i := range s{
    fmt.Println("hi,test data ->",string(i))
  }
  fmt.Println("This string len is ",len(s))
  fmt.Println("You want ",string(s[0:len(s)-1]))
}
```

Comment: hope this helps

Comment: I think this doesn't answer the question, and you seem to not understand what OP is asking

Comment: The question is how to disable the automatic redirect from /Login to /Login/, not how to trim a trailing slash of a string.